# How can I go to the success track of a promise from an error track?

Tags: node.js, promise

So I have this code:

```
aPromise
.then(function(result2){return aFailingPromise;}, function(error) {...})
.then(function(result1){return newPromise;}, function(error) {/*Catch failure, do backup things and go back to correct track*/})
.then(function(result3){return promise;}, function(error) {...});
```

When a failure occurs, every error method that I pass into the promise chain gets called and does not go back to the 'success' track. How can I do this? One of my promises has a possible backup plan, that I want to execute in the error method and perform the rest of the successes.

Comment: whats in your error handler?

Comment: Currently `return response.error(error)` (this promise chain is inside of a Parse define), but I would like to go to the first function (indicating success) on the next item in the promise chain

Comment: What makes you think that the error handlers "*do not go back to the 'success' track*"? That's *exactly* what they do. You might want to have a look at the [difference between `.then(…, …)` and `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572), though.

Answer (score 0):

You return to success if you don't throw/reject in your error handling

```
Promise.reject(new Error('some error'))
  .then(() => console.log('never reached'))
  .catch(e => console.log(e.message)) // some error
  .then(() => console.log('good again as the error is handled above'))
  .catch(() => console.log('never reached'))
```

Comment: So this will catch the error from the previous item in the promise chain? What do I put if I want to end the promise chain?

Comment: you cant really, if you want conditional promise chains you have to nest them. As this it pretty broad i would suggest you to formulate a specific use case/flow. I can help you with that then.